# How to extend an HTML element with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a div that is 50X100 pxs and I want to extend the height to 125 pxs when my mouse enters it. The div's class name is Home. Here's what I have so far:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.Home').mouseenter(function(){
        $('.Home').animate({height: "125px"})
    })
});
```

It doesn't seem to be doing anything. Am I completely wrong or just missing one element or something?

Comment: That seems to be working fine, even though `"125px"` could simly be replaced with `125`. And the second `$('.Home')` could indeed also be `$(this)`. Did you include a link to the library?

Comment: what you have is correct: http://jsfiddle.net/qmjkt8au/ are you sure your markup is correct? maybe you have the case wrong (i.e. 'home' instead of 'Home'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this easily with CSS3

HTML:

```
<div class="home">
la la la la la
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.home{
height: 100px;
background: red;
color: #fff;
width: 50px;
transition: height .5s ease-in-out;
-webkit-transition: height .5s ease-in-out;
cursor: pointer;
}
.home:hover{
    height: 125px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.Home').mouseenter(function(){
        $(this).animate({height: "125px"})
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code worked perfectly fine for me.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.Home').mouseenter(function(){
        $('.Home').animate({height: "125px"})
    })
});
```

You can test here:
http://jsfiddle.net/actvge85/

are you sure you included jquery?

it could also be written:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.Home').mouseenter(function(e){
        $(e.target).animate({height: "125px"})
    })
});
```